# How do I convert time time into minutes from a string?

Tags: c#

heres my code -

```
string TimeOut = File.ReadLines(myfile);
var TimeNow = DateTime.Now;
    
var diffInSeconds = (TimeNow - (DateTime.ParseExact(TimeOut, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).TotalSeconds;
                               
MessageBox.Show("Complete In " + diffInSeconds.ToString("#.##") + " Seconds");
```

My TimeOut string is "08/01/2021 16:12:24"

I keep getting error code

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime.'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` format string: note, that in `"08/01/2021 16:12:24"` you have year (`2021`) at the **third** place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"` should be `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` to match `"08/01/2021 16:12:24"`. The `"yyyy"` matches the *years*, which come first in your example, followed by the months `"MM"`.

Comment: OMG Massive faceplant.

Comment: Happens to the best of us, sometimes it's hard to see the wood for the trees :)